# mssql how to get lock on whole table without select statement?

Tags: sql-server-2005

MSSQL 2005 .I want to get a lock on a table at the start of transaction and only release it at the end of the transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- get lock
BEGIN TRY
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        -- release lock
    END
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    -- release lock
END
GO
```

Does lock on table gets automatically released once transaction has completed or rolledback?

Comment: As long as the transacting process doesn't freeze up before it finishes, yes, the locks are automatically released.  However, not all locks will last that long (some may release when completing a command), unless you specifically set hints to do so.

Comment: how do you get a lock on a table inside the transaction and what will happen to requests coming from other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table locks, or other types of locks, can be set using hints like so:

```
UPDATE Users WITH (TABLOCK) SET Username = 'fred' WHERE Username = 'foobar'
```

Locks will generally expire when the command completes (even if the transaction is not yet done), unless you add other hints to keep them around within the scope of the transaction.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.90%29.aspx for an explanation of all lock types and other table hints.

Locks will affect other users depending on the isolation level of their own transactions.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.90%29.aspx for more info.